# Docker/Node error: Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, docker, enoent

I'm trying to get a simple Dockerfile to run a node application and so far it has been difficult. I have finally got it to run and compile, however I am running into the following error. This is my first dockerfile and I really haven't seen this error before or online:

```
patientplatypus:~/Documents/pypy-sandbox-server:18:42:13$sudo docker run -it compile

> pypy-sandbox-server@1.0.0 start /
> npm install && node api/app.js

npm WARN pypy-sandbox-server@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 1.352s
in app.js - SANITY CHECK
info: Initializing Sandbox
error:  Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1185:14)
```

My dockerfile itself should be pretty simple. The only "tricky thing" I'm doing is composing more than one docker image (this is necessary for my particular use case). The node part (below) is very simple however:

```
FROM node:8 as node_env
WORKDIR .
#COPY package.json .
COPY . .
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install npm
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN npm set progress=false && \
    npm config set depth 0 && \
    npm install
EXPOSE 3000
COPY --from=pypy_build usr/local/bin/pypy ./pypy
#CMD ["forever", "-c","node --harmony","./api/app.js"]
ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: I'm curious why your application is trying to communicate to docker. If it is required by you, you need to mount the docker socket to the container: `sudo docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock compile`